# Запрет на удаление приложения

Tags: android, защита, удаление-программ

Есть приложение и необходимо наложить запрет на его удаление. Есть идея установить его в какую-нибудь папку, а этой папке под рутом назначить права только на чтение.

Какие у Вас есть идеи?

Comment: я бы убивал таких разработчиков.

Comment: Вообще-то все установленные дополнительно программы можно удалить. Если не через маркет, то через Настройки-Приложения. Единственное, что кнопка удалить недоступна для программ, которые уже были в изначальном ROM'e, т.е. были интегрированы в саму прошивку телефона. Но принципиальной разницы между приложениями нет - это все равно банальные APK-файлы, просто раскиданные по разным папкам. Возможно в этом и есть ключ.

Comment: @afiki, не задумывались, что разработчики иногда пишут программы не для себя, а под заказ. Вот заказчики то как раз и бывают с извращенной фантазией.

Comment: не задумывался. наверное потому что не стал бы работать с таким заказчиком.

Comment: @afiki, ну зря вы так. Нужды разные бывают и причины есть, которые вы не учли, прежде чем высказаться. Как говориться: "не зарекайся"(с)

Comment: @afiki: разработчик не виноват, он человек подневольный. А вот заказчику надо бы источник фантазии оторвать.

Comment: Ребят! Если такие требования - в туда такого заказчика. А если будете с ними работать он и вас "туда" заберет! А вы прогинаетесь под недакватных людей. Странные вы...

Comment: Если очень нужно то: - [Disable application unistall in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241362/disable-application-unistall-in-android)
- [Android 4.0 Api to Disable Apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592174/android-4-0-api-to-disable-apk)

Comment: @DroidAlex вы не видите всего, я сам работаю надо проектом, но не вижу в нем ничего плохого, он даже хорош чем то :) и все что просят - оправдано. Если вы с чем то не сталкивались, то не значит что этого не может быть

Comment: Не стоит отвечать, 16% принятых ответов...

А вообще это исконно пользовательская прерогатива - решать, что удалять, а что - нет.

Вообще, была у меня одна программка, которая не удалялась просто так. Там что-то было связано с выбором Администраторов устройства. При установке она запрашивала право сделать ее администратором устройства, и удалялась только после того, как у нее отбирали право администратора.

Можете погуглить на эту тему

Answer (score 2):

Вам придется создать собственные образ системы, который будет содержать ваш apk в сборке. 
Но я не думаю, что усилия будут стоить того. Вы уверены, что это именно то, что нужно? Может вам обойтись без этого?

Answer (score 1):

Установить приложение (например [Smart AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free&hl=ru)) и заблокировать через него приложение с названием "программа установки пакетов"